# how include SQLiter in KMM for both android and IOS

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform

how include SQLiter (https://github.com/touchlab/SQLiter) in KMM for both android and IOS

Need to implement SQLiter in kmm project But There is no official document or Sample .

SQLiter is designed to serve as a driver to power user-friendly libraries rather than something to use directly but if you ever need it, you can find it on mavenCentral:

`dependencies { implementation("co.touchlab:sqliter-driver:$version") }`

Comment: Why you need this library? It designed only for iOS and Windows targets, I suggest you use SQLDelight instead, it uses sqliter for iOS and for android uses android driver.

Comment: Hi @EvgenyK , SQLiter fits my usecase to reuse lot of existing queries as a raw query . And also SqlDelight Doesn't have get ColumnIndexByName in SQLCursor .

Answer (score 0):

**SQLiter** is library for native targets, so you can use it only in `iosMain` section of your `build.gradle(.kts)`.

For Android I suggest you use `androidx.sqlite:sqlite-framework`.

Then you add both dependencies, your `build.gradle(.kts)` will look like:

```kotlin
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    //...
}

kotlin {
    sourceSets {
        //...
        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("androidx.sqlite:sqlite-framework:$sqliteFrameworkVersion")
                //...
            }
        }
        val iosMain by creating {
            dependsOn(commonMain)
            iosX64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Main.dependsOn(this)

            dependencies {
                implementation("co.touchlab:sqliter-driver:$sqliterVersion")
                //...
            }
        }
        //...
    }
}
```

Then you need to create common interface in **commonMain**, please take a look how SqlDelight is doing it [here](https://github.com/cashapp/sqldelight/blob/master/runtime/src/commonMain/kotlin/app/cash/sqldelight/db/SqlDriver.kt)

Then implement interface in **iosMain** and **androidMain** for both drivers. Once again take a look at SqlDelight library: [here is Android](https://github.com/cashapp/sqldelight/blob/master/drivers/android-driver/src/main/java/app/cash/sqldelight/driver/android/AndroidSqliteDriver.kt) and [here is iOS](https://github.com/cashapp/sqldelight/blob/master/drivers/native-driver/src/nativeMain/kotlin/app/cash/sqldelight/driver/native/NativeSqlDatabase.kt)

Basically you can find everything you need in [SqlDelight](https://github.com/cashapp/sqldelight/) repository. Because SQLiter powers the SQLDelight library on native clients.

Answer (score 0):

This is in the shared module:

```
expect fun Scope.sqlDriverFactory(): SqlDriver
fun createDatabase(driver: SqlDriver): ChildrenDatabase {
  println("database created")
  val database = ChildrenDatabase(
    driver = driver,
  )
  return database
}
```

This in the android main module

```
actual fun Scope.sqlDriverFactory(): SqlDriver {
  println("driver created")
  return AndroidSqliteDriver(ChildrenDatabase.Schema, androidContext(), "${DatabaseConstants.name}.db")
}
```

This in the ios main module

```
actual class HttpClientFactory{
  actual fun create() : HttpClient {
    return HttpClient(Darwin) {
      install(ContentNegotiation) {

      }
    }
  }
}
```

And these are the dependencies I used, you don't need all of them:

```
object CashApp {
  object SQLDelight {
    const val gradlePlugin = "app.cash.sqldelight:gradle-plugin:${Versions.sqlDelight}"
    const val androidDriver = "app.cash.sqldelight:android-driver:${Versions.sqlDelight}"
    const val sqliteDriver = "app.cash.sqldelight:sqlite-driver:${Versions.sqlDelight}"
    const val nativeDriver = "app.cash.sqldelight:native-driver:${Versions.sqlDelight}"
    const val sqljsDriver = "app.cash.sqldelight:sqljs-driver:${Versions.sqlDelight}"

    const val coroutinesExtensions = "app.cash.sqldelight:coroutines-extensions:${Versions.sqlDelight}"
    const val primitiveAdapters = "app.cash.sqldelight:primitive-adapters:${Versions.sqlDelight}"
  }
}
```